# asp.net mvc tinymce usage?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        language: "tr",
        elements: "Body",
        mode: "exact",
        height: 400,
        width: 600
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#form_post').ajaxForm({
            beforeSubmit: ShowRequest,
            success: SubmitSuccesful,
            error: AjaxError
        });
    });
</script>
```

html

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("_AddPost", "Posts", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form_post" }))
{
     <div class="editor-label">
          <input type="file" name="File" id="File" />
     </div>

     <div class="editor-label">
         @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostTypeId)
     </div>
     <div class="editor-field">
          @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PostTypeId, ViewBag.PostTypes as SelectList, "--- Haber Tipi ---", new { @class = "custom_select" })
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostTypeId)
      </div>

      ...

      <div class="editor-label">
           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Body)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Body, new { @class = "custom_textarea" })
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Body)
      </div>

      <div class="editor-label">
           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AuthorId)
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AuthorId, ViewBag.Authors as SelectList, "--- Yazarlar ---", new { @class = "custom_select" })
       </div>
       <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AuthorId)
       </div>

       <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsActive)
       </div>
       <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive)
       </div>
       <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsActive)
       </div>

       <div class="submit-field">
             <input type="submit" value="Ekle" class="button_gray" />
       </div>
}
```

model

```
public class PostViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} alanı boş bırakılmamalıdır!")]
    [Display(Name = "Haber İçerik")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    ...

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} alanı boş bırakılmamalıdır!")]
    [Display(Name = "Haber Tipi")]
    public Nullable<int> PostTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} alanı boş bırakılmamalıdır!")]
    [Display(Name = "Yazar")]
    public Nullable<int> AuthorId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Kategori")]
    public Nullable<int> CategoryId { get; set; }

    ...

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} alanı boş bırakılmamalıdır!")]
    [Display(Name = "Yayında")]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool IsActive { get { return true; } set { } }

    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

when I post view tinymce editor content,it does not bind to model property. Other properties bind, ony tinymce not.

I mean in controller action

```
model.Title         // is my expected
model.Description   // is my expected
model.Body          // null
```

controller

```
public ActionResult _AddPost()
{
    using (NewsCMSEntities entity = new NewsCMSEntities())
    {
        // following lines are true. I can see dropdownlist values...
        ViewBag.PostTypes = new SelectList(entity.PostTypes.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.Authors = new SelectList(entity.Authors.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(entity.Categories.ToList(), "Id", "Name");

        return PartialView(new PostViewModel());
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _AddPost(PostViewModel viewModel)
{
    Posts post = new Posts();
    post = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<PostViewModel, Posts>(viewModel);
    PostImages postImage = new PostImages();
    HttpPostedFileBase file = viewModel.File;

    using (NewsCMSEntities entity = new NewsCMSEntities())
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             // add post to db
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
            {
                foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
                {
                     Console.WriteLine(error);
                     // error message model.Body is null
                }
        }
   }
```

All model properties are my expected only Body property is not. What am I missing?

Thanks...

Comment: Could you show the request as seen in FireBug?

Comment: I use Ajax post, and I get 500 error (internal server error). I debugged it I get model state error (Body should not be null)

Comment: Could you show your request payload as seen in FireBug?

Comment: Sorry I don't see the request anywhere in your question. All that you have shown in your updated question is the controller action in which you are saying that `model.Body` is null but I already understood that. The reason why it is null is because your request is probably wrong. Please show the exact HTTP request as seen in FireBug. An HTTP request consists of headers and body. That's what I need to see. Use the `Network` tab of `FireBug` to capture it.

Comment: `There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable&lt;SelectListItem&gt;' that has the key 'PostTypeId'. `

Comment: What is `PostTypeId`? Could you show your code? I cannot help you if I don't know what code you have written. It looks like you forgot to rebind your DropDownList collections in your POST action before redisplaying the view. Also I will repeat it for the last time: could you show the exact request payload as seen in the Network tab of FireBug?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov , I shared all my codes.

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi try changing the `mode:"textareas"` in tinyMCE.init

Comment: @Karthik, there are more than one textarea in a form so, I cant do your suggestion. But, accepted answer is the solution.

Comment: Ok, Thats great ! I just came to know we have TinyMCE for editing in MVC. I tried few tutorials and worked out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick with TinyMCE is that it replaces the textarea with an iframe. In case of standard POST, the TinyMCE handles the updating of the original textarea by itself, but when you put AJAX into play you need to do it by yourself. It can be done in `beforeSerialize` callback of jQuery Form Plugin which you are using:

```
$(function () {
    $('#form_post').ajaxForm({
        beforeSerialize: function($form, options) { tinyMCE.triggerSave(); },
        beforeSubmit: ShowRequest,
        success: SubmitSuccesful,
        error: AjaxError
    });
});
```