# How the form data is converted to a model in C# .Net MVC3 , entity framework?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, model

I have a code like below

View:

```
$("form").live('submit', function () {
var formData = $(this).toObject();

$.ajax({
  url: "../Home/Index",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: formData,
  success: function (data) {<<Some handling>>
}
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult Index(Task task)
{
 //operations on the task object like getting data from task and setting to it.
}
```

**Task** is a model here.
Here when the form is submitted, the form object is directly sent to the controller and the controller is receiving it as a model.
How this conversion takes place? I have added a file component to the form now

```
<input type="file" name = "file" id="file"/>
```

and added the file attribute to model Task.

```
public HttpPostedFileBase file{ get; set; }
```

But I am getting `null` for the file in the controller. But all other values are coming well.

Please help me out. Please let me know if you need any additional info to understand my question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally it's the model binder that is responsible for converting the request values into a model.

But in your case you seem to be attempting to send a file using AJAX. This is not supported. The reason for that is because jQuery's ajax method doesn't support that. You could use [`HTML5 File API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) if the client browser supports it because the XHR2 object allows you to asynchronously upload files to the server. Here's an example:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function () {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(this.method, this.action);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert(xhr.responseText); // handle response.
        }
    };
    xhr.send(new FormData(this));
    return false;
}
```

Also notice that I have used the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to subscribe to the submit event instead of [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) which is obsolete and has been removed in jQuery 1.9.

If on the other hand you need to support legacy browsers you could use a plugin such as [`Fine Uploader`](http://fineuploader.com/) or [`jQuery form`](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) to achieve this task. What those plugins do is detect the capabilities of your browser and if it supports XHR2 it will use it, and if it doesn't it will use a different technique (such as hidden iframes, flash, ...).

Comment: What is the best way from your perspective?

Comment: There is no best way from my perspective. It will depend on your project requirements and constraints. If you need to support legacy browsers you do not have much choice. But if all your clients use modern browsers then you should absolutely use the HTML5 File API which is designed exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Darin Dimitrov.

Answer (score 0):

You can not file upload using jquery ajax post directly. You should you some plug-in for this.
May be you can use [this plug-in](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955560/asp-net-mvc-tinymce-usage) will show you a start point for using this plug in.

Also, I learned it from @DarinDimitov suggestions, too :)